# Dynamodb use begin with query on primary key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have the primary key as "id" STRING "123456", I want to use (begin_with) query on this primary key , I sit possible ?

Comment: You could also have the ID in the sort key as well, then you can do a begins_with.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use `begin_with` on the partition key. The workaround is to create a GSI and query that using `begin_with`.

Comment: can u please give an example for the same, relatively new in dynamo